# How do i fade an image on one side in photoshop cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, cs6, adobe-creative-suite

I want to achieve this particular effect where an image fades into a certain color like the example below.how would i go about it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the easiest method to understand would be using Eraser tool on the photo with a soft round brush (basically a round brush with 0 hardness) and you just erase the part you want to fade to transparency. Then adjust the background color to whatever it is you want to be behind the photo.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Gradient Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/gradients.html)?

Answer (score 0):

First, put a mask on the layer you want to fade out (it's the light rectangle with the dark circle under your layer panel). Select the gradient tool ("G") and hit "D" to set your colors to black/white. Making sure your mask is selected, drag the gradient tool across the layer.

This will create transparency so whatever is behind it can show through. In the example above the bottom layer would be white, the layer above that the image, and the top layer the graphic masked to fade out on either side.